# Приходят письма только на одну почту. Как так?

Tags: сервер

Не могу понять, почему на двух разных проектах, где работают два разных программиста одна и таже ошибка: не приходят письма с сервера на их адреса. НО, приходят только на одну из моих почт. Пробую другую свою почту - не приходят. И так с 3 разными почтами: yandex.ru (на одну приходят письма, на остальные 2 нет), inbox.lv,mail.ru,gmail.com - судя не приходят письма. Как такое может быть? Не понимаю...
Вот для примера: http://inby.eu/mail.php

Что с сервером не так? Тех. поддержка тоже помочь не может...

Пишет:

/var/log/exim4/mainlog и rejectlog

Вывод логов отмененных отправок

:/var/log/exim4# tail -5 rejectlog

2019-01-21 20:41:50 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [37.49..245]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tom@sim-networks.net)

2019-01-21 20:47:47 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [37.49..245]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=philip@sim-networks.net)

2019-01-21 20:53:48 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [37.49..245]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=isaac@sim-networks.net)

2019-01-21 20:59:45 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [37.49..245]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=leon@sim-networks.net)

2019-01-21 21:05:44 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [37.49..245]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=niall@sim-networks.net)

В ФТП не могу найти папку /log/exim4/mainlog и rejectlog . Где они находятся?

Comment: Это обсуждалось примерно 100 раз: SPF, DKIM, DMARC

Comment: Можете, если не сильно затруднит, закопипастить в 101 раз про SPF, DKIM, DMARC ?

Comment: Для этого есть Google. В том числе для поиска ответов на SO

Comment: Как правильно спросить у Google? Пишу SPF - пишет обозначение этого термина. В чём конкретно искать проблему?